# How can I make the imported modules use the same objects as my main?

Tags: python, import, namespaces

My setup is this.
I have an `engine.py` that defines a lot of variables and custom functions that I script and modify in external `script.customextension`. I am using `imp.load_source('script', 'script.customextension')` to import my external scripts, but when I do that all the variables and functions can not be accesssed from the external module.

I have then tried writing this as the first line in the external script: `from engine import *` but then I am re-instantiating all the objects and losing the ones already created that I need access to.

A gross simplification is the following

file `engine.py`

```
a = 10

def f(myval):
    global a
    a = myval
    print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    imp.load_source('script', 'script.ext')
```

and file
`script.ext` has this single line

```
f(20)
```

Results in this when running engine.py:

```
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

Where what I wanted was:

```
20
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's ugly:

```
import __main__ as main

main.f(20)
```

Comment: thanks but I found another approach that works well in my case

Answer (score 0):

I found that this solution could be used instead of importing modules (see [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#exec))

```
    _file = open('script.ext')
    for line in _file:
        exec(line)
```